# How to get or cache the main flutter engine?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-engine

My goal is to display a screen even if the phone is locked I looked for a solution to do that in flutter but I haven't found one. So I want to start a new `FlutterActivity` in android native code but I don't want to create a new flutter engine. Is it possible to access the main flutter engine which is created when the app is launched or to manually create the main engine when the app is launched and cache it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution. I simply override the [`configureFlutterEngine(FlutterEngine flutterEngine)`](https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/embedding/android/FlutterActivity.html#configureFlutterEngine-io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine-) method of the `FlutterActivity` class. There is no need to cache it because it is easy to get it in the `MainActivity` class which inherit `FlutterActivity`, but in case someone needs it:

```dart
FlutterEngineCache
  .getInstance ()
  .put("engine_id", flutterEngine);
```